# Document Management System for Small Business

Tags: windows, file-sharing, document-management

dHi Guys,

Just a questions, I am trying to find out what is a suitable document management system that can replace our physical file management and  reasonable in price.
It's for a small law firm, currently the physical file holds all printed communication, documents, etc in a chronological order. opening the file will give you the newest and flipping back into time to the beginning of the file. 
We have thousands of file based on file number. We would like the system to be integrated with Explorer if possible.. Must be used with a networked shared drive.

Does anyone have any ideas? what to use?

Thanks for looking. :)

Comment: [We really don't do product and service recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), but like @ewwhite and others said you really need a specialized system for this (there are lots of them - Google `Document management system` & possibly tack on `legal` or `law firm`).  You might be able to make due with Sharepoint (which is IE integrated) and some custom code -- if you think that's a good option you can ask ***implementation questions*** on our [sharepoint.se] site...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Microsoft's [Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/default.aspx)? You can grab [Sharepoint Foundation](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/Related-Technologies/Pages/SharePoint-Foundation.aspx) which is free. It's not as much a pure document management solution as it is a collaboration tool, but there are document/knowledge management capabilities there and it does support versioning as requested (last I dealt with it).

Answer (score 1):

You need a real *document imaging* or *records management* solution. Perhaps something more robust than Sharepoint...

That's a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Well, check for [Alfresco](http://alfresco.com). I used it for small period of time and found to be good.